# Creating an "in-memory .sln" when building multiple .csproj files using MSBuild

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, continuous-integration

We have a code project that uses multiple .sln files, each containing projects (some projects are shared by different solutions, i.e exist in more than one solution).

Our problem is that when using Project References, the actual project must also reside in the same solution.

All of these projects are being built using MSBuild on a build server.

I am wondering if it is possible to create an MSBuild script that somehow "imports" all projects into a single MSBuild project, such that it would be the same as if all projects where in fact located under the same Visual Studio .sln file ?

For example, i'd like to have something similar to the following script:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <!-- Builds all *.sln files under this repository. -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <SolutionFiles Include="**/*.sln" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionFiles)" Targets="Rebuild" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Does this mean that MSBuild will construct an in-memory "master project" of all projects, thus overcoming the project reference issue?

Comment: How do you run MSBuild, manually from command line, from script or from code?

Comment: Run it from command line.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the syntax you have above to build the csprojs directly?

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<!-- Builds all *.*proj files under this repository. -->
<ItemGroup>
    <!--SolutionFiles Include="**/*.sln" /-->
    <ProjectFiles Include="**/*.*proj"/>

</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectFiles)" Targets="Rebuild" />
</Target>

</Project>
```

MSBuild will build the Project References by default even if you DON'T have sln files when it's in CommandLine mode.  If you want to omit the project references (i.e. you are serially building things in order) you can just use /p:BuildProjectReferences=false...

Comment: Not sure i understood your suggestion. What would happen when using that syntax (include PrjectFiles) ?

Comment: Suppose i include all project files (100 different .csproj files), does MSBuild create some sort of internal graph knowing which to build first and which to build as project references, etc?

Comment: My example above is quite rudimentary obviously  but for large source trees, Microsoft recommends using Traversal project files (like yours) to manage the build inclusion.

Comment: check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/dd483291.aspx  for more information.  As for your question about MSBuild determining a graph of project ordering, no it doesn't do that.  But it will build Project References automatically so you could just add the primary output csproj files and let the "BuildProjectReferences" feature auto build the dependencies.

Comment: cool, the docs never mention anything about this feature.. i will try that !

Comment: let me know how it goes.  I've implemented quite a few traversal-based build systems with lots of success.  I'd be happy to answer more questions.

Comment: For the sake of concurrency msbuild uses a levels mechanism to decide which projects to build.
It will acquire all projects required to build, including those who are out of context if the BuildProjectReferences property is set to True.
It will then count the maximum dependency level of each project which is the length of the longest reference chain from that project to any other participating project.
It will then build projects in groups by dependency level starting from the highest to the lowest.
This algorithm is equivalent to looping with a query of "What can I build now?".

Comment: +1 This is the single, most useful and succinct answer, both for this question and for similar recursive build questions anywhere! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar and just had multiple .sln files in the same folder all of which refer to some or all of the projects. In my case, I had .sln files for each flavour of build (CI, nightly, release etc.)

So, for example you may have the following projects in *total*:

- website
- website unit tests
- common library
- common library unit tests
- data access library
- data access library unit tests
- website acceptance tests (e.g. Selenium webdriver tests)
- stress tests

You could have the following solutions:

1. **CI solution** (run on commit). This would reference the unit test projects and their targets
2. **Nightly solution** (run every night). This would reference the stress and acceptance test projects
3. **Release solution** (run on demand for releases). This would reference the website, common and data access projects (i.e. no test projects)

This is just a simple example but hopefully helps. Once this solution/project structure is setup I wouldn't see much call for it to change but if a new project is added then it's a quick job just to add to the relevant solutions.

Comment: So u manually create .sln files? Can this be done automatically?

Comment: Manually as these are also held in source control. Eg CI solution includes test projects whereas release solution does not. It took only a couple of mins to create additional solutions

Comment: I am not sure i completely understand your suggestion. Could you elaborate? If i need to manually create the sln, how do i protect myself from having to update new projects that are added every time to the "master" solution file?

Comment: Thanks. This still forces me to do work twice (add project to solution 1, then add it to the solution with all projects). I was looking for some way i can dynamically build a "master project" with all .csproj to build. Not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can write small console application which will find all Solution files and build them. It will even choose the proper MSBuild Version:

Create c# Console Application

Add Reference to Microsoft.Build and use following code

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(args[0], "*.sln", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

     foreach (string path in files)
     {
        RunMsBuild(path);
     }
  }

  public static void RunMsBuild(string SrcDir)
  {
     ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();
     Dictionary<string, string> GlobalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();

     //GlobalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Debug");
     //GlobalProperty.Add("Platform", "x86");
     //GlobalProperty.Add("OutputPath", "c:\\src");

     BuildRequestData buidlRequest = new BuildRequestData(SrcDir, GlobalProperty, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);
     BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(new BuildParameters(pc), buidlRequest);
     if (buildResult["Build"].ResultCode == TargetResultCode.Success)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Build Success");
     }
     else
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Build Fail");
     }
  }
```

After that you can run it from console or script passing the path where to search solution files as argument

Answer (score 0):

** nevermind, i missed the answer below, with the project include commandline mode **

This is going to not be easy or pretty. But #4 below is how it starts getting better if you really want to go a more "full on" build automation and management route like you are asking for.

1) **On the OP example, using MSBuild as scripting**: In your example, this is more of an automation, much like using a shell or batch file, than really gaining you any MSBuild project trickery. See #2 about .sln rules, and #3 about what I think you were hoping this was more doing, but that does something else.

2) **On the "memory only" .sln question**: Fundementally, I believe if you want MSBuild to use a .sln which is required for resoving .sln based project references, then it can't be in a "zero impact" or "memory only" state, and has to be flushed or saved to disk. This is true even if you owned the project system itself as MSBuild will look at the file itself for resolvng references, and expects it to be in the file system as it runs in a seperate process, and with a mind of its own. Thus if you want to use .sln files there have to be actual .sln files. So hopes for a .sln approach with no .sln file cruft are right out. If you run VS to run msbuild it will generate these and need to flush them to disk before MSBuild starts, where they will stay in the "zero impact" state until build... just to be totally verbose and clear.

3) **On the "import .proj" question**: The one similar option that I know of `<Import Project="my/proj/path/mine.csproj"/>` for your purposes, is exactly like a bulk include of files, which will treat those files as though they were a part of that outer project and commpile to that assembly. Is used often by microsft internally. Imports used in this way ignore much of whats in the imported .proj file and are basically looking for the files it contains to include, just like any other file included in the outer project. So I dont think this will get you any farther along, unless you intend to just build all of them in the same assembly anyway. If you do you will have to stucture the included .proj files with this intent, and abuse/structure the outer to include referneces needed by everything and so forth.

4) **Its the reference definition.** There are a ton of options about referneces and wether they get copied, will be assumed to be placed in GAC, or "just dont do anything and trust me they will be there in a app domain search path at runtime".  You can turn most of that cr*p off, and your only dependency is then the build and the language compiler being able to resolve the referenced assembly for its type and whatnbot, in order to compile the dependant assembly you are trying to compile right then. If you think about it, there are a ton of other references that you dont build yourself, that the build picks up and uses to compile with. So the real question may be, "how do I get my automated build in a state where my depenancies I compile act, and look like any other reference?"

Since you control the build, you can be in control the placement of your dlls, and can be in charge of build order. And... you can control the references.

Here is the remaining classic issue:  at design time, if the reference points to a .sln project then you get design time lookup of types from the foreign assembly **without having to build**, if you alter the project to be agnostic, then you will have to compile. You can do some tricky along many lines, including conditional .proj files, where puts the burden on the dev and possibly hand editing to keep it in sync, or pre-build .proj file filters through scripts to fix up the references, or make them non-sln references and force the dev to build the dependancies to resolve types, where they have to make sure the env they use aligns with the build.

---

**So the prob boils down to how the references are defined, and yes any cruft needed by MSBuild needs to be written to disk for MSBuild to funciton, irrespective of VS itself.** You have to pick your poison, as the prob is that you cant define the references both ways at the same time. This is btw a classic build mgmt problem, you aren't alone.

Answer (score 0):

We needed to combine several .csproj files in TFS (Azure DevOps) but exclude others for our standard build/deploy. I ended up with the following .proj file. The important things were

- The target uses `<MSBuild ...` instead of `<CSC` like in Microsoft's examples
- I needed to include `Targets="..."` for each of the build actions (build, rebuild, clean, restore)

I ended up with a file that looks like

```xml
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="one.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="two.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="three.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectReference)" Targets="Build" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Clean">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectReference)" Targets="Clean" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Rebuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectReference)" Targets="Rebuild" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Restore">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectReference)" Targets="Restore" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```